# Put String argument in Range - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have a little problem in VBA, I want to put row and column of Range function in String format like that :

```
    debut = "BH" & LTrim(Str(i))
    fin = "DB" & LTrim(Str(i))
    For Each Cell In Ws.Range("debut:fin")
```

But i have an error, how can i resolve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have done it (`"debut:fin"`), the range is really equal to that string and is invalid. What you need to do is concatenate the 2 strings with a `:` in between with the `&` operator:

```
For Each Cell In Ws.Range(debut & ":" & fin)
```

Comment: + 1 :) Also `"BH" & LTrim(Str(i))` can also be written as `"BH" & i`